# What is the difference between "atomic hydrogen" and "nascent hydrogen"?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrogen

My book ([Comprehensive Chemistry by *Dr. N . K. Verma, S. K. Khanna, Dr. B. Kapila*](https://books.google.co.in/books/content?id=wTqOs3DAoUAC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE71c-IAhGba2s0k8SMFfv39Amj-tcmzej80Fr0kE5Q2Cvtiuy9L6iL-Phu5xE29CaJO_GVlWzXNi3_fy-KLwbXOavuU5v_qEWwMrX1F91yEF9ffn7RZgulI5xjTfLUBiqn2MbMaR)) mentions two forms of hydrogen — "atomic" & "nascent".

It says that these two forms of hydrogen are more or less the same except that the former is produced by passing $\ce{H2}$ gas through an electric arc struck between two tungsten filaments and the latter is formed during chemical reactions in aqueous solutions. For example, $$\ce{Zn + H2SO4 -> ZnSO4 + 2[H]}$$

The book also said that the reactivity order of these hydrogens is

$$\ce{H2} \lt \ce{[H]} \lt \rm atomic~hydrogen$$

But I think  that the reactivity of $\ce{[H]}$  must be same as atomic hydrogen. So please explain the difference between them and also their reactivity order.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is your book by chance very old? From [the Wikipedia entry for "nascent hydrogen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nascent_hydrogen):

> Nascent hydrogen is purported to consist of a chemically reactive form
>   of hydrogen that is freshly generated, hence nascent. Molecular
>   hydrogen ($\ce{H2}$), which is the normal form of this element, is unreactive
>   toward organic compounds, so a special state of hydrogen was once
>   invoked to explain certain kinds of hydrogenations. Mechanistic
>   understanding of such reactions is now available, and the concept of
>   nascent hydrogen is discounted, even ridiculed.

Then, by example of how this concept came to be:

> Reductions of esters to give alcohols using a mixture of sodium and
>   alcohols is called the Bouveault–Blanc reduction. It is an old
>   reaction that has largely been superseded by alternative methods. At
>   the time of popularity, the process caused much puzzlement because
>   esters are unreactive toward hydrogen. It was also known that sodium
>   reacts with alcohols to release $\ce{H2}$. it was concluded that some freshly
>   generated ("nascent") hydrogen was responsible for this remarkable
>   reaction. Subsequent studies have shown that this reaction proceeds
>   via electron-transfer from metallic sodium to the ester substrate
>   followed by protonation of the reduced intermediate. The evolution
>   of hydrogen by the reaction of sodium and alcohol is purely a
>   competitive reaction, the sole benefit being that in the presence of
>   sufficient alkoxide, the sodium/alcohol reaction slows.

So in general, at least toward organic compounds, your relative reactivities of hydrogen species are correct if you take out "nascent" hydrogen so that:

$$\ce{H2} \lt \rm atomic~hydrogen$$

Comment: Then what is the reason behind more reactivity of the so-called nascent hydrogen?

Answer (score -1):

I think better insights into Hydrogen state can be found here starting about page 13:

Title: The Chemical Elements and Their Compounds, Volume I, Sidgwick, 1950

Text: https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.8077/2015.8077.The-Chemical-Elementns-And-Their-Compounds-Vol-i-1950_djvu.txt

Image: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.8077/page/n7/mode/2up

Hydrogen atoms recombine to molecules rapidly and with a large
evolution of heat in contact with certain solids, especially metals.
Bonhoeffer has shown [20] that the efficiency of different metals in
causing the recombination of hydrogen atoms is almost exactly in the
reverse order to their overvoltage values, as the following list
shows; the metals are in the order of their catalytic efficiency, and
the overvoltage stands below each:

```
 Pt > Pd  >  W  > Fe  > Cr  > Ag  > Cu > Pb > Hg(zero)
```

0.000 0.000 0.157 0.175 0.182 0.097 0.19 0.40  0.57

This seems to show that the overvoltage is due to the slowness of recom-
bination of the hydrogen atoms after they have neutralized their ionic
charges at the cathode, and suggests that the activity of ‘nascent hydro-
gen’ is caused by the presence of neutral hydrogen atoms in the liquid.

The heat of recombination of the atoms (51.7 kcals. per gramme) has
been ingeniously utilized by Langmuir in his ‘ atomic blowpipe ’ in which
a stream of highly atomized hydrogen is directed on the metal to be
heated ; this has the further advantage that the hot metal is in a reducing

--

Monatomic Hydrogen pg 17

atmosphere [21] ; according to v. Wartenberg [22] the temperature of the flame
near the electrode, as judged by the reversal of the spectral lines in com-
parison with those of the sun, is 4,600-4,800°. From the heats of reaction
(H + H = H2 + 103.4 kcals. ; 2H2 + 02 = 2H20 + 116 kcals.) it follows
that for equal volumes atomic hydrogen is 34 per cent, more efficient than
‘Knallgas’, and for equal weights it is 24 times as effective.

In the gas the rate of recombination is much slower. A collision of two
hydrogen atoms cannot of itself lead to the formation of a molecule,
because the resulting pair cannot get rid of the energy of reaction, and so
must separate again ; it is only fruitful when there is a three-body collision

2H + M -> H2M -> H2 + M,

so that the energy can be removed as kinetic energy of the H2 + M (where
M of course may be the wall) ; this difficulty arises in all reactions of
association or addition. Various determinations of the rate of recombina-
tion of hydrogen atoms [23] have confirmed this view, and have shown that
the rate is that required by the triple -collision theory ; the half-life of the
atoms is about 1 sec. at 0-2 mm. pressure.